# Refresh the Grid with the latest Data in DATABASE

Tags: jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I am using a grid where I am passing the values to the controller class and saving the data to Database, but if I refresh the page the new changes are gone. The datas that were present before saving the grid will be displayed again. 
Here is my Code Snippet of ajax call.

```
$("#btnSaveJobCode").click(function(){

   var rowscount = $("#activityCodeRatioDistribution").jqxGrid('getdatainformation').rowscount;
   var postdata = "";
   var rows = $('#activityCodeRatioDistribution').jqxGrid('getrows');

 $.ajax({
          url : "saveActivityCodeRatio.htm",
          cache : false,
          type : "POST",
          contentType : "application/json",
          async : false,
          dataType : "json",
          data : JSON.stringify(rows)

          }).done(function(data) {
              alert("Save Successful.");
              $('#activityCodeRatioDistribution').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );

             }).fail(function() {alert("fail");});
       });
```

What should I do to get the latest data from Database at each refresh? I am using Spring MVC and JQX grid. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that you don't need data : JSON.stringify(rows)
data : rows is enough. jquery ajax does it already.

Answer (score 1):

to reload grid use below code after ajax call

```
$("#activityCodeRatioDistribution").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'cells');
```

If your jqxGrid source attribute is retrieving values from DB then above mentioned reload will update the latest values from DB.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call mentioned above are pretty well. I don't think it has any problem.

Are the data being saved in the database? First of all check that manually. 
If no, then correct the code in the controller to save data. 
If yes, then, you have to check the source of the jqxgrid which you haven't mentioned here.
In source, check the 'id' that you have mentioned. jqxgrid doesn't display rows if two rows have same 'id'.

So, it would be better if you had given the snippet of jqxgrid too.

Thanks